# Autofill password in one command on Mac

Tags: macos, sudo

How do I autofill the root password in a single command on Mac? I want to run the following command so that my computer will not sleep while I am downloading, then the computer will shutdown.

I run the following however I am still prompted for the password

$ caffeinate -u -t 7200 && echo  | sudo -S shutdown -h now

Comment: $ caffeinate -u -t 7200 && echo <password> | sudo -S shutdown -h now

Comment: you could also place in a simple bash script and run that as root... just an idea.

Comment: You could use `visudo` to add yourself to `/etc/sudoers` so you don't need a password `mark ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` - replace `mark` with your username.